# What is the Arduino Nano maximum wattage?

Tags: power, arduino-nano, hardware

`Hello,`

I am currently working on a DIY project and I would like to know the Maximum Wattage of a Arduino Nano with a ATmega328 processor. If anyone know what it is it would be a great help.

`Ricky`

Comment: Look in the datasheets for all the major components, and add them together. There's your answer.

Comment: A typical Arduino consumes around 40-50mA. Not sure of the Nano, but it'll probably be somewhere in that ballpark.  It depends what it's doing, of course, and even if you're running it as 5V or 3.3V.  The most accurate answer you can get is to actually measure the current as it enters the board.